# wifi home connection: verify speed

Tags: wireless-networking

How do I verify the exact wifi speed that I am getting from my service proivder. I just want to make sure that I am getting the speed that they are supposed to deliver. Could I check it from iphone as well?

Comment: it is unclear what you want to measure: are you connected to your ISP via wifi? are you connected to your router via wifi? do you want to measure the speed of the "internets" and wifi is actually a non-issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you looking to verify the WiFi speed between your router and your computer, or the download speed from your ISP?

If you're looking to verify the speed that you're getting from your ISP, you may want to try [speedtest.net](http://speedtest.net). If you're looking to verify the speed that your WiFi router is delivering to your computer, you can try using [iperf](https://superuser.com/questions/70399/linux-command-line-bandwidth-speed-tests). Hope that helps!

Comment: There's a speedtest.net iPhone app as well.  It's nice for helping to choose a better hotspot.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are subscribing to internet from your service provider and they gave you a wireless router/modem as part of the package. If so, there's no real need to test the wireless speed specifically. A wifi connection typically has a speed of 54Mb/sec - in practice it's much slower but let's just assume it's a bit slow and you're managing 20Mb/sec.

A broadband internet connection typically provides you 1-10Mb/sec (slower for the 'budget' subscriptions, higher for the more expensive ones). Your internet connection to your provider will almost certainly be much slower than the connection between your wireless device (iPhone, laptop, game console, whatever).

That said, thepurplepixel's suggestion of http://speedtest.net is the place to start. If you're concerned about the wifi speed being somehow worse, the easy way to test that is to run the test on speedtest.net from a computer connected by wifi, and then again from a computer that's directly wired into your router.

Answer (score 0):

There are iPhone and Android wi-fi checking applications, these will most likely display the channels in use locally as you might get better performance by reconfiguring your wireless router to use different channels.